# Inline CSS not working in header.php in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to add a top bar on a Wordpress site. I went to `header.php` and added this:

```
?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   p {font-size:1px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Random text </p>


</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is working on a text editor but not on the site. This is on top of the `header.php` stuff. I just want a simple top bar with text on one side and some images on the other (no theme option). Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: `i just want a simple top bar with text on one side` I do not see any of those in the code.

Comment: it's clear what you want but if you want to force your style over the theme add `!important`. 
e.g  `p {font-size:1px !important;}`

Comment: ok so !important doesnt work but text-alling does for some reason while font-size doesnt,there also is a bottom margin for some reason,i can change with inspect element but not in the code,i am very confused

Comment: remove ?> on the top of the code

Comment: i cant remove ?> when its the first code if i put it below the theme code it works and the css works but it shows below the header,if i remove it it pops an error syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file

Comment: remove ?> from header.php